# Correct notation with composite function & characteristic functions.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, notation

I have the functions

$p: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R; \quad p(x) = \frac12 x + 1$

$q: \mathbb Z \to \{0, 1\}; \quad q(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & x \geq 1 \\
0 & x \leq 0
\end{cases}
$

I know that the function $f \circ g$ is defined. However I'm struggling to figure out what the correct notation would be to write the formula, as a result of $q$ being inside the function.

Comment: Note that $q$ is a piecewise-defined function. Hence your formula for $p\circ q$ will be a piecewise-defined function. Try looking at each case individually.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the two cases $x \geq 1$ and $x \le 0$.

If $x \geq 1$, then $q(x)=1$ and so $p(q(x))=p(1)=\frac{1}{2}+1=\frac{3}{2}$.

If $x \le 0$, then $q(x)=0$ and so $p(q(x))=p(0)=1$.

So you have :

$$p \circ q:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R,x \mapsto \begin{cases}
\frac{3}{2} & x \geq 1 \\
1 & x \leq 0
\end{cases}$$